# Firebase Database Permission denied on 2 root child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

There are my database rules:

```
    "Results" : {
      ".indexOn":["namaGroup"],
        ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "auth !=null",
    },
```

And it's my code:

```
    private void updateScore(final String namaGroup, final RankingCallback<Ranking> callback) {
            questionScore = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            final DatabaseReference ref1= questionScore.child("Results");
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String key = ds.getKey();
    
                        DatabaseReference ref = questionScore.child(key);
                        ref.orderByChild("namaGroup").equalTo(namaGroup);
                        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        GroupScore ques = ds.getValue(GroupScore.class);
                                        sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Objects.requireNonNull(ques).getScore()));
    
                                }
                                Ranking ranking = new Ranking(namaGroup, sum);
                                callback.callBack(ranking);
                                Log.d("TAG", ranking.getNamaGroup());
                                Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(ranking.getScore()));
                            }
    
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                            }
                        };
                        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
                    }
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                }
            };
            ref1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

I get the next error as the warning log: [DatabaseError: Permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUulq.png).

I want to sum a score of each member by looping a snapshot like my code from table results: [Structure of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCGEb.png)

Comment: Post whole file containing rules for your database. Could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rules

```
"Results" : {
  ".indexOn":["namaGroup"],
    ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth!=null",
},
```

Hope this helps Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: i've edited my post and included my database structure, please check a help me to solve this problem dude

Comment: @AgilWahyu I think you have the wrong path. The data is in `Results/Ulangan 1/(key)`. So check the code.

Comment: omg! thanks, i've solve my problem, im using query firebase to orderbyChild

Comment: @AgilWahyu Okay. Happy to hear that!